# Best way to autload class from multiple directory

Tags: php

Hello I'm trying to load classes that are stored in separate directories.
I try with SPL but i must set load directory where to search.

My structure is like in Zend fw:

> |--root
>
> |-- Library
>
> |---- database[dir]
>
> |---------adapter.php
>
> |---------results.php
>
> |-----registry[dir]
>
> |---------format.php
>
> |---------bla-bla.php
>
> |--index.php

```
function __autoload($class_name) 
{
    include LIB."database/".$class_name.".php";
    include LIB."registry/".$class_name.".php";
}
```

How to autoload all from library (all folders) without definig include LIB."database/","registry"

Comment: A load-directory is quite like an include path. One way is to create a PSR-0 compatible autoloader that takes include paths into account. So all that's left to do for yourself is to configure the include path. If that autoloader is then even compatible as well with `spl_autoload` then you don't break anything common.

Comment: Ty for fast replay but i dont understand u. Can u give me litle example?

Answer (score 3):

You could use some conventions with your class names that will help you decipher it's location. Many frameworks use classname conventions for this purpose..

For example:

```
class diseases_autoimmune_lupus{

}
```

You could then `explode()` the class name in your autoload function by the underscore character (`_`) and then use `implode()` with the slash character (`/`) to construct a path to the relevant file.

```
function __autoload($class_name){
  $classParts = explode('_',$class_name);
  $path = '/'.implode('/',$classParts) . '.php';
  include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path);
}
```

In the previous example, the `lupus.php` class is located in the `diseases/autoimmune` folder in your sites root folder. `/diseases/autoimmune/lupus.php`

Comment: this is good but i have big project and i must rename all core class with "CORE_" i will lost to many time for this...

Comment: Making changes to an already existing large codebase is always hard work - but usually worth the effort :)